# Can you use a single weapon for two weapon fighting that is not double?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, two-weapon-fighting

There is a special rule that a [double weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/) can be used for [TWF](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/) or be two handed.

> Double Weapons: A character can fight with both ends of a double weapon as if fighting with two weapons, but he incurs all the normal attack penalties associated with two-weapon combat, just as though the character were wielding a one-handed weapon and a light weapon. The character can also choose to use a double weapon two-handed, attacking with only one end of it. A creature wielding a double weapon in one hand can’t use it as a double weapon—only one end of the weapon can be used in any given round.

The [combat two weapon fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting) rules state

> If you wield a second weapon in your off hand, you can get one extra attack per round with that weapon.

The two weapon feats do not change this wording, simply that the attacks by your offhand are reduced. However as demonstrated by the double weapon, a single weapon can be used for both attacks.

There is an [FAQ](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/)

> What kind of action is it to remove your hand from a two-handed weapon or re-grab it with both hands?

And answers that both letting go and re-grabbing it are free actions.

So the question is, would you be able to adjust your grip and use two handed weapon with two weapon fighting? I except that the answer to this will also answer if a single one handed or light weapon can be used for TWF if you switch hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. The key part of the rule for two-weapon fighting is

> If you wield a second weapon in your off hand,

Note, specifically, it says second weapon. Not one weapon, switched between hands. Two weapons at the same time.

How you grip a weapon does nothing for determining whether or not it can be used for Two Weapon Fighting in any case but Double Weapons. The special exception for Double Weapons is simply there to allow a character to make use of that sort of weapon logically and flexibly - you can choose to ignore the extra 'pointy bit', and just use it as any other two-handed weapon if you choose, or you can make use of both ends at once. Note that this is exactly the same choice a character would have if holding a weapon in either hand - you can choose, round to round, whether to attack with one or both of those weapons. When only wielding one weapon, you will not incur two-weapon fighting penalties.

The FAQ you quoted about switching hands on a weapon does not change how you fight. If you are holding a two-handed weapon, and let go with one hand, you are (generally) no longer able to wield the weapon (see [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons#TOC-Light-One-Handed-and-Two-Handed-Mel) for handedness of weapons). In some cases, you can use the same rule/FAQ to regrip a single handed weapon (to be able to add more of your strength modifier to a particular hit), or to switch the grip on a flexible weapon like the Bastard Sword.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you can double-hand a single-handed weapon, outside of flexible weapon types such as Bastard Sword as you seem to indicate is possible, to add more of your strength modifier to your hit? (Not trying to challenge you, just a general query that I think would improve that last paragraph.)

Comment: @royalmurder Note that I said 'to a hit', not 'to hit'. You can actually wield any one-handed weapon (note - not light weapon) for an extra +50% Str to damage, just check out the link. Also, I know better than to say there's no other benefit...I'm sure, tucked away somewhere in the plethora of Pathfinder rules, there's some reason to do it for a weapon other than a Bastard Sword.

Comment: well... I'll be damned. I've been playing one handers wrong all this time....

Comment: Doesn't the first weapon become the second weapon when hands are switched? While I understand the reasoning, I don't think this makes a strong case.

Comment: No, it's the same weapon, just in a different hand...